# Implement a search-function in mat-selection-list

Tags: angular, angular-material, ngrx

I have been searching around for a solution for this but cant figure it out how this should me made.
Here is a stackblitz of what im almost looking for, but i dont want it to appear like a dropdown list. 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yo2o9o?file=app%2Fapp.component.html

I would love to have a list like my own code below, but implement a search field over the list and use it to filter users$ depending on the input (but still saving the selected users) ...

Edit: Found this one, https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-i3pfu2-xgembc?file=app%2Flist-selection-example.ts,

This is how it should look, but i cant get this to work with my code..

Html:

```
<div class="userContainer">
    <p>Choose participants</p>
    <mat-selection-list class="form-group" #selectedUsers formControlName="users">
      <mat-list-option *ngFor="let user of users$ | async" [value]="user">
        {{ user.name }}
      </mat-list-option>
    </mat-selection-list>
    <p>Invited users: {{ selectedUsers.selectedOptions.selected.length }}</p>
  </div>
```

users$ is coming from an selector from my state

```
this.store$.dispatch(new fromUsers.GetUsers());
this.users$ = this.store$.pipe(select(fromUsers.getRelevantUsers(+this.userId)));
```

And this is the form i'm using..

```
createEventForm() {
 this.eventForm = this.fb.group(
   {
     users: [null],
     more inside...
   }
  );
 }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A "filter search" is't only a FormControl, you subscribe to valueChanges and, using switchMap and debounce return a list, well, in code. If you has an array of values and a formControl

```
  search = new FormControl();
  typesOfShoes: string[] = ["Boots","Clogs","Loafers","Moccasins","Sneakers"];
```

You create an observable

```
$search = this.search.valueChanges.pipe(
    startWith(null),
    debounceTime(200),
    switchMap((res: string) => {
      if (!res) return of(this.typesOfShoes);
      res = res.toLowerCase();
      return of(
        this.typesOfShoes.filter(x => x.toLowerCase().indexOf(res) >= 0)
      );
    })
  );
```

And use

```
<mat-form-field >
    <mat-label>Search</mat-label>
    <input matInput [formControl]="search">
  </mat-form-field>

<mat-selection-list #shoes [formControl]="shoesControl">
  <mat-list-option *ngFor="let shoe of $search|async" [value]="shoe">
    {{shoe}}
  </mat-list-option>
</mat-selection-list>
```

See [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ygmipl?file=src/app/list-selection-example.html)

**Updated** As Charlie point, the problem is that if we change the search, you loose the values checked, so we can NOT use `[formControl]="shoesControl"`

So, we are going to use the event (selectionChange) of the mat-list and the property [selected] of the mat-option to change the value of the FormControl

So, we are going to has

```
<mat-selection-list #shoes 
  (selectionChange)="selectionChange($event.option)" >
  <mat-list-option *ngFor="let shoe of $search|async" 
   [value]="shoe" [selected]="shoesControl.value && 
                shoesControl.value.indexOf(shoe)>=0">
    {{shoe}}
  </mat-list-option>
</mat-selection-list>
```

See that there're no [formControl], but remember that a FormControl exist if we has an input or not. Well the function selectionChange received as argument an object with the property selected and value, so we has

```
selectionChange(option:any)
{
  let value=this.shoesControl.value || []
  if (option.selected)
    value.push(option.value)
  else
    value=value.filter((x:any)=>x!=option.value)
  this.shoesControl.setValue(value)
}
```

NOTE: I updated the stackblitz

Comment: Thank you!!! Now the search-function is working fine :) The only problem i have left is that the selectedUsers resets everytime i'm doing a new search.. do you know how to solve this?

Comment: Sorry, Charlie, I don't take account about this. I updated the answer, we can not use directly [formControl]="...", we need "work" with (selectionChange) and [selected] (I updated the stackblitz too)

Comment: ❤️ Thank you!!!!!!!!!!!! This is amazing. I suggest `Set()` instead of a `FormContol` for holding values. It's light weight, prevents duplicated items, and has builtin methods for adding, removing, and checking for items. This was necessary because I have added a custom checkbox to select/deselect all items. My new code was sometimes causing duplications in the list of values.

Answer (score 0):

I did similar in angular 15, but without any FormControl. I hold the current selections, and add them back into my filtered list.  This keeps them selected and also on screen.

Html:

```
<mat-form-field>
    <mat-label>Filter by Name or Type</mat-label>
    <input matInput (keyup)="applyFilter($event)" placeholder="Ex. email">
</mat-form-field>

<mat-selection-list #attachments>
    <mat-list-option *ngFor="let att of filteredAttachments" [value]="att.uuid" [togglePosition]="'before'">
        <div>{{att.name}}  <span class="float-right">{{att.type}}</span></div>
    </mat-list-option>
</mat-selection-list>
```

TS:

```
@ViewChild('attachments') attachments: MatSelectionList;
filteredAttachments: Attachment[] = [];

applyFilter(event: Event) {
    let filterValue = (event.target as HTMLInputElement).value;
    filterValue = filterValue.trim().toLowerCase();

    // filtering a List will lose current selections, if they don't match the filter.
    const currentlySelected = this.getCurrentlySelected();
    this.filteredAttachments = this.data.attachments.filter((entry: Attachment) => {
        return (entry.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(filterValue) >=0) || entry.type.toLowerCase().indexOf(filterValue) >=0 || currentlySelected.includes(entry.uuid);
    });
}

private getCurrentlySelected(): string[] {
    const selected = [];
    for (const selectedOption of this.attachments.selectedOptions.selected) {
        if (selectedOption.selected) {
            selected.push(selectedOption.value);
        }
    }
    return selected;
}
```